Uncommitted work pending issue in Test using - System.runAs()
I need to run the test as two different users because the approveForm contains a validation prohibiting the creator of the form to approve it. But in my test for approve I have constantly been facing the "Uncommitted work issue", making my callout fail. Here is the code:
getForm retrieves current form or creates a new one if none exists, which is also the only time it would use DML (not the issue, been checking the logs). getAccount is a SOQL for retrieving the account.
Controller
@AuraEnabled
public static ChangeAddressForm approveForm(Id caseId) {
    ChangeAddressForm form;
    try {
        form = getForm(caseId);
        validateForm(form);

        form.successes = new List<String>();
        form.errors = new List<String>();

        if(isValid(form)) {
            Account acc = getAccount(form.data.Scope__c);
            // Conditional statements are used to determine which values should be changed,
            // to prevent overwriting to null values
            if(isSpecialAddress) {
                acc.Special_Address1__c = form.customerForm?.specialAddress1;
                acc.Special_Address2__c = form.customerForm?.specialAddress2;
                acc.Special_Careof__c = form.customerForm?.specialCareof;
                acc.Special_City__c = form.customerForm?.specialCity;
                acc.Special_Zipcode__c = form.customerForm?.specialZipCode;
            }
            if(isForeignAddress) {
                acc.Foreign_Address1__c = form.customerForm?.foreignAddress1;
                acc.Foreign_Address2__c = form.customerForm?.foreignAddress2;
                acc.Foreign_Address3__c = form.customerForm?.foreignAddress3;
                acc.Foreign_Country_Code__c = form.customerForm?.foreignCountryCode;
            }
            if(isNameSurname) {
                acc.LastName = form.customerForm?.lastName;
                acc.FirstName = form.customerForm.firstName;
            }
            // Webservice callout
            IntCust.UpdatePersonAccount(acc,false,isSpecialAddress,isForeignAddress);

            form.data = FormService.approveForm(form.data);
            update acc;
            form.successes.add(FormService.APPROVED_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw CommonUtil.auraException(e);
    }
    return form;
}

Test method
@isTest
static void testApproveForm() {
    Case testCase = [SELECT Id, AMF_Customer_Id_FF__c FROM Case LIMIT 1];
    Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
    User creatorUser = TestDataFactory.getSysAdminUser();
    User approverUser = TestDataFactory.getTestCRMUser();

    Test.startTest();
    System.runAs(creatorUser) {
        Form__c testForm = TestDataFactory.createForm(testCase.Id, 'ChangeAddress', acc.Id.toString(), 'Foreign Address;Special Address', '{"specialZipCode":"54321","specialCity":"Updated City","specialCareof":"Updated Care","specialAddress2":"Updated Special Address 2","specialAddress1":"Updated Special Address 1","lastName":"User","foreignCountryCode":"NO","foreignAddress3":"Updated Foreign Address 3","foreignAddress2":"Updated Foreign Address 2","foreignAddress1":"Updated Foreign Address 1","firstName":"Test"}');
    }

    ChangeAddressForm approvedForm;

    System.runAs(approverUser) {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TestWSMockCustomer(true));
        approvedForm = ChangeAddressFormController.approveForm(testCase.Id);

        System.assertNotEquals(null, approvedForm); 
    }
    Test.stopTest(); 
}


The "Uncommitted work pending" issue occurs because Salesforce does not allow callouts to be made after DML operations within the same transaction. To resolve this, you need to ensure that all DML operations are completed before making any callouts. -https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385708&type=1

Test.startTest() documentation states

Any code that executes after the call to startTest and before stopTest is assigned a new set of governor limits.

You currently have a dml, TestDataFactory.createForm(), after calling Test.startTest(), that's why you get "Uncommitted work pending" issue.
Just move Test.startTest() right before System.runAs(approverUser) and everything should be fine:
@isTest
static void testApproveForm() {
    Case testCase = [SELECT Id, AMF_Customer_Id_FF__c FROM Case LIMIT 1];
    Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
    User creatorUser = TestDataFactory.getSysAdminUser();
    User approverUser = TestDataFactory.getTestCRMUser();

    System.runAs(creatorUser) {
        Form__c testForm = TestDataFactory.createForm(testCase.Id, 'ChangeAddress', acc.Id.toString(), 'Foreign Address;Special Address', '{"specialZipCode":"54321","specialCity":"Updated City","specialCareof":"Updated Care","specialAddress2":"Updated Special Address 2","specialAddress1":"Updated Special Address 1","lastName":"User","foreignCountryCode":"NO","foreignAddress3":"Updated Foreign Address 3","foreignAddress2":"Updated Foreign Address 2","foreignAddress1":"Updated Foreign Address 1","firstName":"Test"}');
    }

    ChangeAddressForm approvedForm;

    Test.startTest();
    System.runAs(approverUser) {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TestWSMockCustomer(true));
        approvedForm = ChangeAddressFormController.approveForm(testCase.Id);

        System.assertNotEquals(null, approvedForm); 
    }
    Test.stopTest(); 
}

